# How to add an image to the post preview in the free theme "food recipes"

Tags: images, themes

I'm making my first wordpress site. When I publish a post I see it in my home page but despite I add an image I can't see it above the post title in my home page. [image]

Thank you in advice.

Comment: May you clarify your question more? From what I understand, you are not seeing your featured image that you've assigned to the post?

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: Featured images vary for each theme, what theme are you using?

Comment: It's Food recipes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question, it's hard to exactly determine when you say:

> *...I add an image I can't see it above the post title...*

Also, considering that you said this is your first wordPress site, I am going to assume you added the in **within your Post** and not set it as a **Featured Image** which is what usually determines the image of the post on your homepage. Be sure to do the following:

1. Open your post and on the right hand side, you should see a box label **Featured Image**
2. Click **Set featured image** and choose or upload your image
3. **Update** your post and you should see your featured image on the homepage

It should look like the following in your post:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to change **get_the_id()** with **get_the_ID()** in following files.

```
index.php:
full-width.php:
left-sidebar.php:
single.php:
$foodrecipes_feature_img_url = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_id()));
```